# Pandas value_counts() with stack on only one column

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I want to find out the number of devices per brand. Actually, the stack (). Value_counts () method is correct, but it also calculates the column it should not calculate. It somehow expects both columns and returns them.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine # database connection

disk_engine = create_engine('sqlite://gender-age-train.db')

phones = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT device_id, phone_brand FROM gender_age_brand_train', disk_engine)

print phones.stack().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
小米                      17336
三星                      13706
华为                      13001
OPPO                     5802
vivo                     5658
魅族                       4710
酷派                       3349
联想                       2695
金立                       1124
HTC                      1015
中兴                        861
乐视                        760
索尼                        717
努比亚                       484
LG                        333
中国移动                      275
TCL                       222
朵唯                        213
海信                        204
优米                        192
锤子                        191
一加                        174
语信                        170
天语                        159
奇酷                        140
摩托罗拉                      103
酷比                         67
酷比魔方                       64
华硕                         59
美图                         57
                        ...  
-8865310564646824401        1
8985202332281820721         1
-5322234356626416887        1
880050530112722484          1
-4671567474474098396        1
3635321738417886774         1
-632936314824337863         1
-1422720271682152902        1
-2873804282202335925        1
3654370499756512829         1
-6683814535312746946        1
-339536654867409365         1
-6550235263773354456        1
-576216080894831095         1
7567434598341760535         1
8744410044312016395         1
8050431495959696911         1
-1419919517746506224        1
1300102583374534161         1
7324848588154164755         1
1622918197035226644         1
4016294717867992903         1
-4702856771680607231        1
-2474276408301741600        1
4390245982607697285         1
8161044391542216225         1
-6548201155232442846        1
-2950848600346765789        1
2164451555009058340         1
1586233736345944064         1
Length: 74765, dtype: int64
```

It should actually only calculate the column with the brands. So stop where ... then come. I tried a lot but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
#extract only column for count from db
phones = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT phone_brand FROM gender_age_brand_train', disk_engine)
#select only column for count from df
print phones['phone_brand'].value_counts()
```

---

I think you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html), [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html) or [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html) if need count `phone_brand`s by `device_id`s:

```
#count and sort values
print phones.groupby('device_id')['phone_brand'].value_counts().reset_index()
```

Or:

```
#count also NaNs and not sort
print phones.groupby(['device_id','phone_brand']).size().reset_index()
```

Or:

```
#NOT count NaNs and not sort
print phones.groupby(['device_id','phone_brand']).count().reset_index()
```

Comment: You have made a lot of changes and improvements, I thank you very cordially :) But your first answer, has helped me very far. I have adapted the query: SELECT phone_brand FROM gender_age_brand_train; and then applied it like this: phones ['phone_brand']. value_counts ()
If you like you can also add this version again, would be helpful for others. Many Thanks!